# Proof that $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{f(x)}{f(x) + f(1-x)}dx = 1/2$, where $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is strictly positive and continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

I'm trying to prove this for Riemann integration (not very rigorously, just finding an outline for how the proof should go). The substitution $y=1-x$ seemed handy, as I got 
$$\int_0^1 \frac{f(x) - f(1-x)}{f(x) + f(1-x)}dx = 0,$$ but I could not continue after that. Can anybody give me some kind of hint?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2333724/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/995201/42969 – all found instantly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Bf(x)%7D%7Bf(x)%20%2B%20f(1-x)%7Ddx%20%3D%201%2F2%24&p=1)

Comment: I apologise, I must have searched for the wrong keywords then, as I couldn't find the question anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then you know that$$\int_0^1\frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)}\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1\frac{f(1-x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)}\,\mathrm dx.\tag1$$But it follows from the substitution $y=1-x$ that the RHS of $(1)$ is equal to its LHS. And since their sum is $1$, you're done.